# Bash closes on launch. Might be due to switching development modes

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When trying to launch 'Ubuntu' or 'bash' the window opens and immediately closes.

The reason might have been that I switched to different Insider Edition of Windows 10 or developer mode, and forgot that WSL needed it.

I switched it back to 'Developer mode' and WSL Windows feature was already enabled, but a restart did not help. And executing 'wsl' and 'bash' brings the following in command prompt:

```
C:\>bash                                                                                             
No such interface supported
```

What do I do to have it working properly again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you install any of the recent builds from the Fast ring and switch to the Slow ring – optional content such as enabling developer mode will fail. You will have to remain in the Fast ring to add/install/enable optional content. This is because optional content will only install on builds approved for specific rings.

Or rather, I switched the Insider pacing.

> [ADDED] WSL will not work on this build. If you require WSL to work, you can rollback to **Build 18267**.
>   There is an issue in this, **Build 18272**, build that makes WSL inoperable. When trying to launch your distribution you will see a “No such interface supported” error. The issue has been fixed and will be in next week's Insider Fast build. If you've installed this build you can roll back to the previous Windows build using “Go back to the previous version of Windows 10” in Settings->Update & Security->Recovery.

---

Fixed in **Build 18277**